# AngularJS with a HUGE application

Tags: angularjs

I would like to use angular with a huge application, but because of the way the DI works, Angular needs to load every services of every module during the boot, and so I have the feeling that my application can become very slow.

Does someone have an experience with this case ? We are looking at angular2, but the resources are limited at the moment ...

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If your huge app is one big SPA, then you *have* to load all the things, because you don't know when navigation will take you where.

Some apps can consist of several independent subapps. In this case, navigation between subapps involves full refresh, but also each subapp is its own angular module, has its own set of dependencies and you can render only those dependencies when showing the subapp.